# Transition Back to Sign In View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, segue

On sign-out, I am trying to take the user back to the sign-in page. I've tried both instantiating the sign-in VC and pushing onto the navigation stack as well as performing an unwind segue. The former I've read is bad for memory and the latter didn't even animate a transition perhaps due to how my view hierarchy is set up.

Is there a recommended best approach to accomplish this action? The following is my view hierarchy:

**Initial Nav Controller** (logic to initialize sign-in VC vs tab bar VC based on user auth status) -> **Sign-In VC** (on sign-in pushes tab bar VC onto stack)

**Tab Bar VC** -> **Nav Controller** -> **Home VC** -> **Nav Controller** -> **SignOut VC**

Answer (score 1):

#### There is a problem in the way you show the Sign in in view controller.

Sign in view controller shouldn't be pushed into the navigation controller stacks. The best way, is to present the Sign in view controller modally. That way, you have the ability to show the Sign in view controller wherever you are in the application.

**1** During the launching process in `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions)`, you could simply do:

```
yourTabBarController.present(signInViewController, 
                             animated: false,
                             completion: nil)
```

This will make sure your Sign in view controller cover the screen. The user couldn't access whatever behind it.

Notice that I use `animated: false` to avoid showing the main screen to the user.

**2** After you check the credentials, and the sign in succeeded, you could simply do:

```
signInViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This will dismiss the login view controller that's covering the main screen, and show the actual main screen.

**3** Whenever you want to redirect the user to the login screen (for example: After user click sign out), you do:

```
yourTabBarController.present(signInViewController, 
                             animated: true, // Now we add animation.
                             completion: nil)
```

This will show the Sign in view controller again. The Sign in view controller will cover the main screen, and there's no way for the user to access the main screen.